# Trying to convert a numerical tuple into a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert and concatenate a numeric tuple into a string on python. I receive something like this from an Angular controller

```
data['permissions'] = (43,12,65,34,67)
```

then I send it to a `model.py` to concatenate this values as a string like that:

```
values = data['user'], ",'", str(data['permissions']), "'"
```

When I'm running the code, python console show me an error that can convert tuple array into str implicitly. I tried some different methods to concatenate and convert the tuple:

1. This

   ```
   permissionsList = ','.join(data['permissions'])
   values = data['user'], ",'",permissionsList, "'"
   ```
2. and this

   ```
   pointer = 0;
   values = int(data['user']),",'"
   for value in data['permissions']:
       if (pointer == 0):
          values += str(value)
          pointer += 1
       else:
          values += ','+str(value)
   ```

And get the same error. Values should be like this: `34,'43,12,65,34,67'` (I need this format to process a query).

Comment: `','.join(str(i) for i in (43,12,65,34,67))`? At the moment you seem to be mostly building *more* tuples, not strings.

Comment: You might use any other string that should be the seperator of the items at the beginning. `','.join(…`

Comment: pitting commas between your strings will not work when you make `values`, this simply makes *another* tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to convert the tuple into list, then cast the element in list from int to str.
the example is below

```
user = 45
permission = (43, 12, 65, 34, 67)
final = "{},'{}'".format(user, ','.join(str(p) for p in permission))
print(final)
```

the output will be

> 45,'43,12,65,34,67'

## edited for your case

```
final = "{},'{}'".format(data['user'], ','.join(str(p) for p in data['permission']))
```

Comment: "casting" with `list` is completely unnecessary. So is your list-comprehension that overwrites `permission`. Just use `", ".join(str(n) for n in permission)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the tips, i will update my answer

Comment: But you are still using `list(data['permission'])` and why do `permission = [str(x) for x in permission]` when you are doing `", ".join(str(p) for p in permission)` in the very next line?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga edited again, that thing i forgot to delete

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast each item in the tuple to string first before attempting to join:

```
','.join(map(str, data['permissions']))
```

`map` simply calls `str` on each item in your tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why nobody wrote the simplest solution.

```
data['permissions'] = (43,12,65,34,67)
str_data_permissions = str(data['permissions'])
```

Then you get all the numeric tuple as a single string.