# Converting numeric tuple to a string

Tags: python, string, integer, tuples

I have data that looks similar to following:

```
q = (0,0,0)
```

I wanted to convert the numeric tuple to a string. Many people on the internet offered a solution that looked like this:

```
user = 45
permission = (43, 12, 65, 34, 67)
final = "{},'{}'".format(user, ','.join(str(p) for p in permission))
print(final)
```

Source: [Trying to convert a numerical tuple into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553046/trying-to-convert-a-numerical-tuple-into-a-string).

Unfortunately, I kept getting an error message that read: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. So, I tried other solutions like this `','.join(map(str, q))`. No avail.

Is there something wrong with my application? Please help. Expected output:

```
q
"0" "," "0" "," "0"
```

or the following as string:

```
0,0,0
```

Comment: Could you provide your expected output please?

Comment: added expected output.

Comment: you are printing user also, should it be in the expected output or not

Comment: This answer is from the question you linked: `','.join(str(x) for x in q)` and works with your tuple just fine.

Comment: The code in your question prints `45,'43,12,65,34,67'`. What would you like the result of that input be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a mix of list comprehension and `','.join()`:

```
q = (0,0,0)
output = [j for j  in [','.join([str(x) for x in q])][0]]
```

This outputs:

```
['0', ',', '0', ',', '0']
```

Edit: Given OP accepts the string as is too, you can avoid the outer list comprehension and just use:

```
','.join([str(x) for x in q])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user = 45
permission = (0,0,0)
final = "'{}'".format(','.join(str(p) for p in permission))
print(final)
```

this returns `0,0,0`